# Finding probability that the function of a random variable is less than another random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

X and Y are random variables, whose joint density function is $f(x,y)$ for $\infty<x<\infty$ and $\infty<y<\infty$. I am trying to find $P[X^2<Y]$.

Here's how I plan on solving the problem:

1) Find the marginal density function $f_X(x)$.

2) Let $Z=X^2$ and find the marginal density function $f_z(z)$.

3) Find the joint density function of Z and Y, over which I can integrate over the area $Z-Y=0$.

However, I am stuck on step 3. Since I am not told whether X and Y are independent to begin with, I do not know to find the joint density function of Z and Y.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proposed strategy is far too complicated. Let $D$ be the region above the curve $y=x^2$. You want
$$\iint_D f(x,y)\,dy\,dx.$$
This in a sense finishes things if we do not know $f$. You can express the integral, if you wish, as an iterated integral, $y$ goes from $x^2$ to $\infty$, $x$ then goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\mathbb{P}(Y>X^2) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(Y>X^2 \vert X=x)f_X(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(Y>x^2)f_X(x) dx$$
Hence,
$$\mathbb{P}(Y>X^2) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(1-F_Y\left(x^2 \right)\right) f_X(x)dx = 1-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F_Y\left(x^2 \right)f_X(x)dx$$